# int values doesn't compare in hbase filter using SingleColumnValueFilter

Tags: java, hbase

Compare int values with specific qualifier isn't working.

I tried using `new BinaryComparator` but it doesn't work.

```
FilterList fl = new FilterList();

SingleColumnValueFilte filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
        Bytes.toBytes("dynamic"),Bytes.toBytes("speed"),CompareOp.GREATER_OR_EQUAL,
        new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes(10));
```

I tried both `"10"` and `10` but it doesn't work.

```
fl.addFilter(filter);
Scan s = new Scan(Bytes.toBytes("235091871:2015-01-01T00:02:58"),Bytes.toBytes("235091871:2015-01-01T00:22:19"));

System.out.println("hello scan");

s.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("dynamic"),Bytes.toBytes("speed"));

s.setFilter(filter);

ResultScanner rs = table.getScanner(s);

for (Result res : rs) {
    for (KeyValue result : res.raw()) {
        System.out.println(Bytes.toString(result.getRow())+" "+Bytes.toString(result.getValue()));
    }   
}
```

I have speed values like 10.3,10.4,11.1,9.6,8.3

The output should be `10.3,10.4,11.4` when I process or filter using `CompareOp.GREATER_OR_EQUAL`.

If I need to write a custom comparator please suggest how to do it with code.

Comment: Could you make the `It doesn't work` part more specific?

Comment: Which means i pass arguments as string="10" and int = 10